# How to get/set video.currentTime via a prop in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, svelte

I am working on a Svelte component that wraps a video tag. I am trying to make it so that you can explicitly set the 'playbackTime' prop to change the currentTime of the video. However, I would also like to update this prop when the video's currentTime changes as a result of playing the video so I can show it in the user interface.

Is something like this possible?

```js
<script>
  export let playbackTime = 0;
  let video;

  $: playbackTime, () => {
    if (propWasSetBySomethingOtherThanTheTimeupdateEvent()) {
      video.currentTime = playbackTime;
    }
  };
</script>

<video on:timeupdate={() => playbackTime = video.currentTime} bind:this={video}>
  <!-- video sources -->
</video>

Time: ${playbackTime}
```

I basically want to make `playbackTime` a proxy for `video.currentTime`. I realise I could expose video and get/set `currentTime` directly but I'd rather keep this variable private to the component.

One idea I had is to set a flag when the `timeupdate` event triggers and then unset it afterwards so I can tell whether the `playbackTime` was set by the event, but that seems prone to race condition bugs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't get race conditions in JS unless you use asynchronous code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detecting where changes come from is not supported right now.

Not quite sure what you mean by keeping the variable private, you export a property that corresponds to the time, so I would recommend just using a binding like this:

```html
<video bind:currentTime={playbackTime} ...>
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems really obvious now. :-)